# React Native Navigation: navigate between screen (really need help)

Tags: react-native

I'm new react native and i have a problem with react navigation. I don't know how to navigate to Screen1 from Home. Home includes 2 components from 2 js files. 
When run app, we start at Home with 2 components and from Home, we click on TouchableOpacity, then navigate to Screen1, but it's not working with my code below

file Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';

export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Component1 />
            <Component2 />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

file Route.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './Home';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';

export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home_Screen: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Screen_1: {
        screen: Screen1
    },
    Screen_2: {
        screen: Screen2
    }
}
)
```

file Component1.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class Component1 extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
               onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen_1')}}> // it's not working
                <Text style={{ color: '#fff', padding: 10, fontSize: 15 }}>Go to Screen 1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

file App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { HomeStack } from './Test/Route';


export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <HomeStack/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `navigation` prop is only available inside the `screen` components, not the sub/child components of the `screen`.

In your case `this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen_1')` will work from the Home screen. But not inside `Component1` or `Component2`. If you want to use `navigation` prop inside them, you have to send it as a prop,

**`<Component1 navigation={this.props.navigation} />`**

Now you can access the `navigation` prop inside Component1

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @RaviRaj answered, you can also use the [withNavigation wrapper](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html) if your Screen is deeply nested. But in this case, if your screen component is only 1 or 2 layers deep, pass navigation as a prop!

Comment: thanks you for your advice. i want to ask about it too